# How do I get dashundergaps to go to the end of line?

Tags: formatting, packages, gap

I am using the `dashundergaps` package to print fields to be hand-written.  Is there a way to have the dots or dashes to fill the full line ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply fill the `\gap{}` with `\hfill` :

```
\gap{\hfill}
```

You can conveniently write a new command suiting your needs, e.g. :

```
\newcommand{\fillgap}{\dotuline{\hfill}
```